# Get rid of Thumbs.db when publish in VS 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, publish

I changed publish setting, Items to deploy to "All files in this project". Publish not succeed due to error when coping Thumbs.db to temporary path before publish.

> Error 49  Copying file help\GenderType_help\images\Thumbs.db to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\help\GenderType_help\images\Thumbs.db failed. Could not find file 'help\GenderType_help\images\Thumbs.db'.

How could I get rid of these unwanted Thumbs.db files to be published.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I could not find the exact answer this is what I done to contain all the files in copy project.

1. Changed Items to deploy to `Only files needed to run this application`.
2. Change Build action property of all files to `Content`

Then the all project files with in the copy project without having items to deploy to "All files in this project".

Answer (score 2):

Find the file thumbs.db in your project solution explorer - might need to turn on the show all files setting. Delete the file Thumbs.db from the solution. Then Publish

Answer (score 0):

You can make Windows stop creating them, here are two guides;

https://www.sitepoint.com/switch-off-thumbs-db-in-windows/

http://www.howtogeek.com/210764/fix-file-in-use-deletion-errors-on-network-drives-by-disabling-windows-thumbnail-generation/

Comment: Yeah, it's a way but, finding a option without disabling image thumbs or delete that particular directory thumbs only...